# Specifying value of each pixel in a superpixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, superpixels

I could specify superpixels for an image an their properties.

```
  L = superpixels(A, 200);
    K=regionprops(L, 'PixelIdxList');
```

I know that mean intensity value of each superpixel could be specified as follows:

```
K=regionprops(L, 'MeanIntensity')
```

The question is how it is possible to specify values of all pixels within a superpixel?

Comment: This line gives an error: `K=regionprops(L, 'MeanIntensity')` That's one of the options that can only be used on grayscale image data, not a label matrix like you get from `superpixels`. You'll have to loop over the array `K` and use the pixel index list to collect a vector of values for each labelled region in the original image `A`.

Comment: That should probably be `K=regionprops(L, A, 'MeanIntensity')`.

Comment: When you say "specify values of all pixels within a superpixel", do you mean you want to get the values of all pixels within each superpixel, or that you want to set their values in an image. The former is `K=regionprops(L, A, 'PixelValues')`. The latter needs a loop, as shown in [the documentation page for `superpixels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/superpixels.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo,@gnovice,In MATLAB 2018a argument A produces error.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Thanks for your comment, the case is the former, however it doesn't work for RGB image. Is there any work around to use it for those images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for getting a list of all pixel values within each label is `K = regionprops(L, A, 'PixelValues')`. But this only works for grey-value `A`.

The simplest solution is to iterate over the channels, and call the above function for each channel:

```
A = imread('~/tmp/boat.tiff'); % whatever RGB image
L = superpixels(A, 200);

n = size(A,3); % number of channels, typically 3
K = cell(max(L(:)),n);
for ii=1:n
   tmp = regionprops(L, A(:,:,ii), 'PixelValues');
   K(:,ii) = {tmp.PixelValues};
end
```

We now have a cell array `K` that contains the values for each labeled pixel: `K{lab,1}` is the set of values for the pixels labeled `lab`, for the first channel.

The following code collates the components of each pixel into a single array:

```
K2 = cell(size(K,1),1);
for ii=1:numel(K2)
   K2{ii} = [K{ii,:}];
end
```

Now `K2` contains RGB arrays of data: `K{lab}` is a Nx3 matrix with RGB values for each of the N pixels labeled `lab`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the error I face it is Error using cell
Size inputs must be scalar.

Error in pixsvalue (line 5)
K = cell(max(L),n);

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. How the variable "lab" should be defined in MATLAB because of the error : Undefined function or variable 'lab'?